# Is there a good treeview control supports ajax searching,filtering?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been searching for a javascript treeview control which supports 'on the fly' searching, filtering (similar to auto complete box).

I found ExtJS which has that feature but it's too big (~800 KB js). I also like jquery TreeTable control but I'm not sure it supports that feature.

Please advise. Any suggestion is welcome, thanks a lot.

Comment: Any more suggestion fellows? Please help, thanks.

Comment: I started a bounty in the hope that somebody knows a treeview control similar to ExtJS tree control & its filtering feature.

Comment: ExtJS js file is pretty large. If you do go that route I would ajax it in after the home page loads so the user can dl it without knowing and have it available when they need it.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo), it does come along with some nice plugins, such as a json plugin to fetch nodes from a server, as well as a search plugin.

It's not a perfect solution for your desired search behavior but you may use this to your advantage:

**"The search plugin enables searching for nodes whose title contains a given string, works on async trees too. All found nodes get the jstree-search class applied to their contained a nodes - you can use that class to style search results."**

So if you know that all nodes get this class, you could easily hide all nodes beforehand and then let the search plugin add this class which overrides(!important) the display attribute of the css class.

Comment: thanks Nick. I came across it before. Is there a plugin to search & "shrink to results" on the fly? The link you gave me only highlight search result.

Comment: You mean, you show only nodes which have been hit by the search?

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is a hack. I need to show result nodes & their parent nodes too.

Comment: You should consider writing your own plugin then. If you stumble across a tree component which does exactly what you want, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at this article [8 Useful JQuery TreeView Examples](http://www.programmingsolution.net/useful-js/jquery-treeview.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TreeView](http://obout.com/t2/ht_searchText.aspx) component from obout.com.  It's ASP.NET, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.addobject.com/nlstree this is a commercial solution, but the best I have come across. Well documented, quite flexible and has a good overall performance. Its behavior can be easily extended using various events it exposes.

If this one doesn't work for your requirement, better start coding one.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/). Its light and good.

Answer (score -2):

800 KB in a web site or web application is not too much nowadays.
Enter Google, type "jquery treeview plugin" (instant search turned on) and you'll download about 250 KB and you didn't even blinked.

I'm not *the* big fan of Ext JS and I'm amazed of jQuery + jQuery UI + plugins + jQuery tools, etc. But Ext JS TreeView is incredibly useful and ready to be used.

There are [lots of possibilities with TreeView](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-8) (even TreeGrid, which I think is the TreeTable your are looking for).

You can also try to create your own Ext JS treeview bundle (they used to have an Ext JS builder, but it's not available any more) with just required dependencies.

I think the main problem when using Ext JS is when you draw complex interfaces, like:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/desktop/desktop.html

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/index.html

But you can try a complex example of TreeView (a TreeGrid) and you'll see it's not too much:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/treegrid/treegrid.html

Hope this helps

Comment: 800k today is as much as 800k 5 years ago. And until some days ago I had a slow UMTS internet connection, and 800k are a lot. Also, the net does not need to be filled with unnecessary data.

Comment: Mobile clients and the slow networks put us back like 5-10 years so being load efficient is as important as in the past.

Comment: It's 800K + 200K jquery + plugins + stylesh*t. It's too much for a web 2.0 project...